# KML document works, but when written programatically, the encoding is wrong?

Tags: xml, kml, google-earth

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <name>cwvtrial.kml</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>PawneeNationalGrasslandBirdingLoop</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-104.336274,40.642254,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>PawneeButtes</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-104.00072,40.814517,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>TamarackRanchStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.804758,40.822466,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>RedLionJumboReservoirStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.669417,40.896904,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>PrewittReservoirStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-103.328779,40.430521,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>JacksonLake</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-104.096527,40.391156,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>SouthPlatteRiverEagleDrivingTour</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-103.826038,40.266986,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>GreaterPrairieChickenLeks</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.219793,40.238643,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>BonnyLakeStateParkSouthRepublicanSWA</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.255351,39.620417,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>FlaglerReservoirStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.994292,39.293958,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>LimonWetland</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-103.677844,39.258691,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>SimlaPronghornLoop</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-104.033625,39.160838,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>KinneyStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-103.43689,38.906778,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>FountainCreekRegionalPark</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-104.726281,38.722361,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>ChicoBasin</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-104.345359,38.651998,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>RockyFordStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-103.682054,38.065433,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>AdobeCreekReservoirStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-103.268029,38.256757,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>QueensStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.722507,38.334479,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>WillowCreekPark</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.61408,38.077685,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>JohnMartinReservoirStateWildlifeArea</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-102.988342,38.034914,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

So I got this to work when I took out the first name tag under the document tag. The real problem comes in when I try to use another file (which looks exactly the same to me) that I am creating by parsing an xml document with a Java program. I can load the file created in Notepad, but it gives a not-well-formed error when I try to load the file produced by the program. Something to do with my encoding? But I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Notice the ` character at the end of the file.

Comment: Nothing is wrong! It works out of the  box!

Comment: It still does not work for me. The ` character is not present anymore.

Comment: The file seems perfectly valid to me.  [It works in Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_kmlQuestion_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=37.6,-95.665&sspn=56.805293,44.384766&t=m&z=8) (don't have Earth).

Comment: Please accept my answer (check mark) which was the correct answer to your posted question. (Rememeber the mismatched Tags are not containined in your posted kml file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was mismatched tags. Makes you feel dumb, but seems to happen a lot in programming. Little things that are easy to miss. So make sure to check the tags well. Wasn't the encoding at all.

Comment: But the mismatched tags you don not have posted in your question, I have given the correct answer to your question. The file works.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file to xml, and open in Internet Browser or any other Xml Editor. Then you see if you have an Problem with mismatched open close Tags.

I checked your file, it works!

yellow Marks, Placemarks in USA. All Fine.
Check you Google Earth installation.

Please note: to display a km lfile on google maps, the file has to be located on a public reachable URL. Google Earth has not this limitation

Comment: I checked through, all tags appeared to be matched.

Comment: This might help. Here are some tips to validate KML -- http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#Basic_Validation

Comment: So I am going to Google, then Maps, My Places, Create Map, then Import, and lastly trying to load my kml file. Is that the right way?

Comment: @setherj No, you put that file, on your hard drive, and double click, then Google Earth opens. If not then download Google Earth. To display a kml in Goggle Maps, the kml file has to be located on a public reachable server.

Comment: It looks, like that you have some dirty charachters in line 3 at the filename. I copied and paste from stackoverflow, so this corrected your formatting error. Do the same: copy from stackoverflow

Comment: It may be the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Check if you can disable it in your text editor.

Comment: @setherj Just open notepad on windows, copy file into, and save. This will remove all dirt.

Comment: So I got this to work when I took out the first name tag under the document tag. The real problem comes in when I try to use another file (which looks exactly the same to me) that I am creating by parsing an xml document with a Java program. I can load the file created in Notepad, but it gives a not-well-formed error when I try to load the file produced by the program.

Comment: @setherj Ok, obvously your program is not set to UTF-8 encoding. fix the output.

Comment: I am new to Java, so I am not sure how to change my output to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @setherj There normaly is not a need for that. Just dont use strange characters for filenames, no äöüé´etc.

Comment: I checked the encoding and it said it was UTF-8, so now I am lost as to why my program's output file will not work in Google Earth nor Google Maps.

Comment: @setherj becaue your filename in line 3 is garbage! first try use a fixed one like "test.kml"

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I found that it was some mismatched tags that I didn't see.

Comment: @setherj if you want you could accept the answer, since the posteed file works

Comment: I changed my question though. I did upvote, because it was helpful.